# PyQt/PySide QGraphicsScene, Hover event on Ellipse Item not working

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, qgraphicsview

I'm currently learning how to use Qt's Qgraphics and i cant get the hoverEnterEvent to work on an QGraphicsEllipseItem object. I am setting setAcceptHoverEvents to True and implemented the hoverEnterEvent function, yet the function isn't getting called.

here's my code:

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QMainWindow,
    QGraphicsView,
    QGraphicsScene,
    QGraphicsEllipseItem,
)
from PySide6.QtGui import QPainterPath, QTransform, QPen, QBrush, QColor, QPainter
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt


PORT_PEN_COLOR = "#000000"
PORT_BRUSH_COLOR = "#ebebeb"
EDGE_PEN_COLOR = "#474747"


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 800, 600)
        self.setCentralWidget(GraphicsView())
        self.show()


class GraphicsView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.setScene(GraphicsScene())
        self.setRenderHint(QPainter.RenderHint.Antialiasing)


class GraphicsScene(QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setSceneRect(-10000, -10000, 20000, 20000)
        self._port_pen = QPen(QColor(PORT_PEN_COLOR))
        self._port_brush = QBrush(QColor(PORT_BRUSH_COLOR))
        self._edge_pen = QPen(QColor(EDGE_PEN_COLOR))
        self._edge_pen.setWidth(4)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        clicked_item = self.itemAt(event.scenePos(), QTransform())
        if event.buttons() == Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton:
            if clicked_item is not None:
                # edge item
                pos = clicked_item.scenePos()
                pos.setX(pos.x() + 6)
                pos.setY(pos.y() + 6)
                self.edge = self.addPath(QPainterPath())
                self.edge.setPen(self._edge_pen)
                self.start_pos = pos
                self.end_pos = self.start_pos
                self.update_path()
            else:
                x = event.scenePos().x()
                y = event.scenePos().y()
                # port item
                start_port = Ellipse()
                start_port.setPos(x - 6, y - 6)
                start_port.setPen(self._port_pen)
                start_port.setBrush(self._port_brush)
                start_port.setZValue(10000.0)
                self.addItem(start_port)
                # edge item
                self.edge = self.addPath(QPainterPath())
                self.edge.setPen(self._edge_pen)
                self.start_pos = event.scenePos()
                self.end_pos = self.start_pos
                self.update_path()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() == Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton:
            print(f"moving, x : {event.scenePos().x()}, y : {event.scenePos().y()}")
            self.end_pos = event.scenePos()
            try:
                self.update_path()
            except AttributeError:
                pass

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event) -> None:
        released_item = self.itemAt(event.scenePos(), QTransform())
        if event.button() == Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton:
            if released_item is not None and released_item.type() != 2:
                self.end_pos = released_item.scenePos()
                self.end_pos.setX(self.end_pos.x() + 6)
                self.end_pos.setY(self.end_pos.y() + 6)
                if not self.start_pos.isNull() and not self.end_pos.isNull():
                    path = QPainterPath()
                    path.moveTo(self.start_pos.x() - 1, self.start_pos.y() - 1)
                    path.lineTo(self.end_pos)
                    self.edge.setPath(path)
            else:
                x = event.scenePos().x() + 1
                y = event.scenePos().y() + 1
                end_port = QGraphicsEllipseItem(0, 0, 10, 10)
                end_port.setPos(x - 6, y - 6)
                end_port.setPen(self._port_pen)
                end_port.setBrush(self._port_brush)
                end_port.setZValue(10000.0)
                self.addItem(end_port)

    def update_path(self):
        if not self.start_pos.isNull() and not self.end_pos.isNull():
            path = QPainterPath()
            path.moveTo(self.start_pos.x() - 1, self.start_pos.y() - 1)
            path.lineTo(self.end_pos)
            self.edge.setPath(path)


class Ellipse(QGraphicsEllipseItem):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setRect(0, 0, 10, 10)
        self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)

    def hoverEnterEvent(self, event) -> None:
        print("hovered")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

What am i doing wrong here, how do i get the hover event to work please ?
Thank you

Comment: Hover events are received only when the *scene* handles mouse movements. You never called the base implementation of `super().mouseMoveEvent()`. Also note that when mouse buttons are pressed, **no** hover event will ever be dispatched, since such events are only created when *no* mouse button is pressed.

Comment: Thank you, I made the changes you suggested and it worked.

Comment: I will try to implement a solution for hover events while pressing a mouse button and will post here if i achieve it.

Comment: I believe you didn't understand: you can *not* receive hover events while pressing the mouse button: that's how the Graphics Scene works, if mouse buttons are pressed, *no* hover event is *ever* created (and, thus, received).

Comment: I did understand that, i'm thinking about using the itemAt function to setBrush() and then reset it to its original color on mouseRelease.